# How to convert base price currency to currency currency price in js Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have product item price with 30KWD and i want to display it checkout order summary  with converting currency price

like: selected currency  is USD

so it will be display like $96

how to convert in js

Answer (score 0):

obviously you can't convert it in JS file.
Simplest way is get desire rate in specific PHTML file and assign it to any global JS variable.
After that in js where you want to change currency just multiply it by rate.